# Placing electricity, cable, phone and internet transmission lines tight together

Tags: noise

Will this cause noise in the phone and internet signal? also placing them through concrete with absolutely no air space around them.

This is happening in one of my friends house, he has issues with noise on the phone, the phone and internet company are the same, so the same noise also causes issues with the internet, it's just one cable since it's from the same company. I went to check outside and noticed that the guys who built the concrete roof, built it around the cables, also placed them tightly together, 110v and 220v together with the phone/internet one. They didn't even bother to use a pipe, no, they just built the concrete roof around the cables.

Comment: In Australia, it is a mandatory safety requirement for power cables and comms cables to be separated. All it takes is one accident with a power drill, to short a power cable to a telephone cable, then the telephone handset someone's holding goes live and they cop 240VAC to the ear...

Answer (score 1):

Recommend your friend to fix it fast as possible. I believe the minimal problem here is the noise on communication cables. Think on the safety of this arrangement... What does occur if some of cover of the cables are lost? (this can be done by rodents, currents beyond specified, accidents etc) Hope his protection circuit, at least, is well-done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tightly bounded phone and data cables tied to parallel runs of power cables, will cause noise.